# What is new_time equivalent in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to convert "to_char(trunc(new_time(sysdate('GMT','PST' )) -1,'Mon-YY')" Oracle query  into snowflake. Could anyone please help me.

Comment: You'll get better results from these questions if you explain what the code is supposed to do and provide sample data with desired results. One line questions tend to get down voted and closed, as you've seen. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then rephrase your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

Convert_timezone is the function in Snowflake that converts a timezone of a timestamp.

```
select convert_timezone('America/New_York', 'UTC', current_timestamp::timestamp) ;
```

For more information you can refer snowflake docs [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html)